# Laravel without Blade - Controllers and Views

Tags: laravel

I am more efficient at setting up my view logic with straight up php. Blade is cool but it's not for me. I am trying to translate all the Blade specific examples and docs to just php. I don't like the fact that I need to assign all the variables for my views in an array of View::make(). I did found all of this so far.

controllers/home.php:

```
class Home_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public $layout = 'layouts.default';

    public function action_index()
    {
        $this->layout->name = 'James';
        $this->layout->nest('content', 'home.index');
    }

}
```

views/layouts/default.php:

```
// head code
<?php echo Section::yield('content') ?>
// footer code
```

views/home/index.php

```
<?php Section::start('content'); ?>
<?php echo $name ?>
<?php Section::stop(); ?>
```

I am greeted with this error: `Error rendering view: [home.index] Undefined variable: name`. I know that `$this->layout->nest('content', 'home.index', array('name' => 'James'));` works but that negates my point about having to send all my variables to an array. This can't be the only way.

The view templating docs doesn't seem to touch on doing variables with nested views from controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how I'm templating with laravel.

```
Class Products_Controller extends Whatever_Controller {

  public $layout = 'layouts.main';

  public function get_index()
  {
   // .. snip ..

    $view = View::make('home.product') 
        ->with('product', $product); // passing all of my variable to the view

    $this->layout->page_title = $cat_title . $product->title; 
    $this->layout->meta_desc = $product->description;

    $this->layout->content = $view->render(); // notice the render()
    }
}
```

my main layout looks like

```
<html>
<head>
<title> {{ $page_title }} </title>
<meta name="description" content="{{ $meta_desc }}" />
</head>
<body>
{{ $content }}
</body>
</html>
```

and the home/product page looks like

```
<div class="whatev">
<h1> {{ $product->title }} </h1>
<p> {{ $product->description }} </p>
</div>
```

Hope that helps you clear some things up

Comment: I'm surprised that people are voting up for this answer, which is out of the topic?! question was about avoiding blade, where this sample uses it?!

Answer (score 5):

you can pass variables this way;

```
class Home_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public $layout = 'layouts.default';

    public function action_index()
    {

        $this->layout->nest('content', 'home.index')
                ->with('name', 'James');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it has been a while on this question, but since it was asked, Laravel 4 has come out and there are newer ways to do things.

If you are reading this these days you should consider using View Composers to prepare the data for your views.

Example:

```
class MyViewComposer {

    public function compose($view){
        $view->title = 'this is my title';
        $view->name = 'joe';
        ...
        $view->propertyX = ...;
    }
}
```

After setting up your view composer register it with the app:

```
View::composer('home.index', 'MyViewComposer');
```

For more information check out the laravel docs on view composers:

http://laravel.com/docs/responses